# how to create Array object in proper order with non existing key value mapping as blank value

Tags: javascript

```
var my_array = [{
    'name': 'asdsad',
    'email': 'masdas',
    'phone': 'dsfdsfsdf',
    'login name': 'abc'
}, {
    'name': 'asdsad',
    'phone': 'dsfdsfsdf',
    'login name': 'abc'
}, {
    'name': 'asdsad',
    'email': 'masdas',
    'phone': 'dsfdsfsdf'
}];
```

Our expected key order of keys is `login name`, `email`, `name`, `phone`.

We would also like to have non existing key value pair with blank value.

here is what I try to do I want to convert json to CSV and it not fill data in proper column block with proper key and if in json object any key element is messing or not in proper order then csv data not comes on expected format

http://jsfiddle.net/vUnF9/2344/

Comment: An object is an unordered collection so this doesn't really make sense. Do you want instead to sort the array or what? BTW, how this array is generated?

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as a JSON array. What you have there is an array containing objects. Also note that the order of an objects keys cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think you meant an array containing some objects

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks, * slaps own head *

Comment: Elements you put in array are javscript objects, not key-value arrays and therefore you can't choose those properties by their position (because they don't have one), as in e.g. PHP arrays and trying to do so is very wrong. As for your second question - what do you mean by having non-existing key value pair? If you mean key without value, you could do that right away, e.g. {key: ''} or {key: undefined} or you could try to create prototype for particular object type.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you getting stuck on? Any existing code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_json_array = [
    { 'name': 'asdsad', 'email': 'masdas', 'phone': 'dsfdsfsdf', 'login name': 'abc' },
    { 'name': 'asdsad', 'phone': 'dsfdsfsdf', 'login name': 'abc' },
    { 'name': 'asdsad', 'email': 'masdas', 'phone': 'dsfdsfsdf' }
];

for (var i=0; i< my_json_array.length; i++){
    for(key in my_json_array[i]){
        if(!my_json_array[i].hasOwnProperty('name')){
            my_json_array[i].name='';
        }
        if(!my_json_array[i].hasOwnProperty('phone')){
            my_json_array[i].phone='';
        }
        if(!my_json_array[i].hasOwnProperty('email')){
            my_json_array[i].email='';
        }
        if(!my_json_array[i].hasOwnProperty('login name')){
            my_json_array[i]['login name']='';
        }
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(my_json_array));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52dtsrv8/)